# How to show the posts of some category first, and then all other

Tags: wp-query, loop

How to show the posts of some category first, and then all other posts that does not belong to that category?

I have logic that get the category and reorder the posts. But i don't know how to use. Please help.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key'  => '_event_end_date',
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    'meta_value' => $today,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '10'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Can you provide your code. :)

Comment: @ksr89 see updated question

Comment: In your code their is nothing about category only about `meta_key` and `meta_value`.

Comment: i want to list all category.but some category comes to first.

Comment: It can not be done with one query. You will need to use two different queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in one query. You have to add second query to show the posts of another category. Like

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'cat' => 4 //category id.
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args ); // Get all the posts category which you want to show first.

$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'cat' => -4 //Display all posts exclude this category.
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args2 ); // Get all the posts category which you want to show second.
```

For reference check here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters